# Domain controller failed to restore using windows backup tools

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Domain controller failed to restore using windows backup tools
One Issue:

One 08 R2 domain controller with fully daily backup(only one controller in this company) is out of services due to  hardware issue.

The below two methods i tried to recover to the new purchasing server,but it is fail.

1)First Method:

Using the windows 2008 R2 CD to boot and carry out recover from backup.
    Everything is OK, but after reboot it will come out blue screen and restart again.

2)Second Method:

a)Install the OS in this new server

b) Reboot the server to DSRM.

c)Using the Windows Backup Tools to restore the system states only

After reboot, it will come out the blue screen error and restart again.

I know this is may be the different hardware issue, but how to resolve? Or can we only restore the AD services not whole system status?
Any suggestion?

Comment: Please tell me you have more than one domain controller?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a driver problem. The new hardware (i guess storage) is not being recognized by the restored windows. From memory, you got an option to supply storage drivers.

What is the Blue screen code ? 7B ?

Else it could be that the previous or this one have one small utility partition. It changes the partition number in boot sequence. You need to change the partition number to boot or create a small fictive partition before restoring. If it's there, check the boot sequence through bcdedit